# Anybody seen the quick find dialogue box in VS2015 go very small?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

For some reason the quick find box (CTRL-F) in VS2015 has gone absolutely tiny. It's almost unusable. Has anybody seen this?

[image: TinyBox]

I can extend it width wise, but absolutely can't change it's height to make the text in it more legible.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the font instead of the box.  It would help if you remember tinkering with the Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors dialog.  It has a "Use Defaults" button, consider clicking it.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a fresh, clean, install of Visual Studio 2019 and I have the same issue :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment from Hans was right track. I clicked on "Use Defaults" which then made the quick find dialogue box small as well as the editing text in the editor small. I then held ctrl and right mouse up to zoom in and everything is a readable size again.

The important thing is not to increase font size if the text is to small, but to zoom in. Otherwise you'll find other parts of VS are still small.

Comment: In VS2017, there is a zoom-scale dropdown in the lower left of the source window.  You can reset it to exactly 100% there.

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone else has this problem, I finally figured out how to fix it on my VS2015 without resetting everything...

1. Place the cursor anywhere in the text editor.  Hold down CTRL key and use the scroll wheel on your mouse to enlarge the search box until it is the size you want.  This will make everything in your code editor huge.
2. Open Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors.  "Text Editor" should already be selected.
3. Change the font size to another other than was you see.  If it's 10 and you want it to be 10, change it to something other than 10, then go back in and change it back to 10.

Comment: This is silly. Don’t mistake me, I appreciate the answer and it does indeed seem to be the only way to resolve the problem. But it is silly that the VS *seems* to offer configurability under Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts And Colors->Find Results but this has no effect at all.

Comment: You're a genius! 10x

Comment: This helps also in vs2017, high DPI hurts MS, again and again.

Comment: Works in VS2019 - this was really bugging me. Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: 6 years later...Works in VS2022 - sort of! The reason it's tiny is the search box scales using your document zoom percentage. So it's better to set your editor font size in Options rather than using the zoom. Or at least use a small default font size like 10

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. 
1. Fonts and Colors - Find Results Window - set to 12-14

2. The font in entire text editor became very small
3. CTR + Mouse Scroll  ----- increase font, EVERYTHING got increased, including FIND
4. Fonts and Colors - Find Results Window - set back to 9, nothing changed.

I have no idea why this worked, especially 2 and 4

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no separate font size for quick find window.

You should set Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor to an approriate size. For a 4k 27inches monitor, font 12 works well. Then set the text editor zoom in factor to 100%.